# how to implement windowDidEndSheet

Tags: swift, macos

I need to find out how to implement windowDidEndSheet for my MacOS app. I had a bug that I reported to apple and they suggested to use this however the apple documentation on this is terrible.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class ViewController: NSViewController  , NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        NSApplication.shared.windows.first?.delegate = self

    }

    func windowDidEndSheet(_ notification: Notification) {


    } 

}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the tip, worked exactly as I wanted to.